# How can I format a simple title page?

Tags: titles, overleaf

[image]

I am wondering how to format a title page like this centered in the page.

Comment: Vertical centering can be done by putting `\vspace*{\fill}` above and below.  Adding text at the bottom will raise the centered part unless you `\smash` it (overlap).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what document class you're using, or specify any relevant packages. Because of that, it's hard to give an exact answer. I can only suggest looking at the `titling` page and [its documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf).

Here's an example using the article class. I've also defined commands for inserting the TA name and class section info in addition to the standard commands for titles, authors and dates.

```
\documentclass[titlingpage]{article}

\usepackage{titling}

% make title large, bold, centered
\pretitle{\vfill\begin{center}\bfseries\Large}
\postdate{\end{center}}

% make author block large, bold, centered, raised, followed by TA, section
\preauthor{\vspace*{-3ex}\begin{center}\bfseries\large by\par\bigskip}
\postauthor{\par\bigskip TA: \theTA\par\bigskip\theclasssection
\end{center}}

% make date of submission pushed to bottom, centered, bold
\predate{\vfill\begin{center}\bfseries\large}
\postdate{\end{center}}

% define new commands for additional fields
\newcommand{\theTA}{}
\newcommand{\TA}[1]{\renewcommand{\theTA}{#1}}

\newcommand{\theclasssection}{}
\newcommand{\classsection}[1]{\renewcommand{\theclasssection}{#1}}

% set fields
\title{Experiment Title}
\author{Student (or Students') Name(s)}
\date{Date of submission}
\TA{TA's Name}
\classsection{Lab Section, Group, Day of week and time of lab}

\begin{document}

% typeset titlepage
\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

There are lots of ways to tweak that, and it may be necessary to take a different approach, especially if you're using a non-standard document class.

[image: title page example]